# How to use classes from another project?

Tags: java, eclipse, development-environment

I have got two Java projects inside Eclipse. Now I want to use classes from project A in project B. I added project A to the build path of project B. But the classes are not available in project B.

What could be the reason for that problem?
Did I do something wrong?
What and how should I do?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: The problem was that the classes to be imported were in the default package.

Comment: I got it. I used the default package in project A. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: Sorry but using the default package never solves anything. Probably you just touched another thing to get it work.
Now that's everything working, try to refactor some of your classes on project A putting them into a package.

Comment: Diega, c0d3x said using the default package was the problem, not the solution.

Comment: What's "default" package?

Answer (score 2):

Verify if in the build properties of Project A under the "Order and Export" tab you have the source folder checked.

Comment: I added a dependent project B to my project A. What difference does it make if I select or deselect the tick box under `Order and Export`? Seems like it makes no difference in my case. Also, in what way does the ordering matter?