# Java Eclipse : Is it possible to pass arguments between different projects?

Tags: java, eclipse

In Eclipse, is it possible to pass arguments between different projects? I want to run two separate projects simultaneously and would like for project A to be able to initialize something in project B, based on user input. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have to different instances of project A and B running. If so, you have plenty of options and this really depends on your requirements.

You can implement a TCP Server in project A and in the other project you implement a TCP Client which will invoke some initialization (see [this example](https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/)). A more high level programming approach is the usage of Java [Remote Message Invocation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html) but this requires a third project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your problem is similar to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910532/how-to-call-a-class-from-another-project-in-eclipse) other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255265/can-we-call-another-project-java-class-from-our-project-in-eclipse), [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792812/calling-a-class-in-another-project-eclipse)? Not too sure if you're asking for more other means of passing arguments/other arguments?